# ValidateButton to test all entries in a repeatable

Tags: java, jenkins, jelly

- I need to check validate a number of fields in one operation with a validateButton,
- this has worked fine with multiple fields
- I've recently introduced a repeatable section, containing multiple checkboxes
- I'm easily able to address these by name in the save operation and get the true/false values
- when I try to pass the same to the validateButton with the 'with' nothing changes in the formData that gets sent (despite referencing the new repeatable stuff)
- I've tried adding a field declaration in the following places...

  - on the outer entry
  - on the repeatable itself
  - on the nested entry
  - on the checkbox itself

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out this isn't possible just using the the 'with' attribute of the [f:validateButton](https://jenkins-ci.org/maven-site/jenkins-core/jelly-taglib-ref.html#form:validateButton), even when the repeated entry is bound to a field (either the repeatER or the repeatED component).

I was eventually able to implement this using the [f:invisibleEntry](https://jenkins-ci.org/maven-site/jenkins-core/jelly-taglib-ref.html#form:invisibleEntry) and some javascript functions (called on the *onclick* of my repeated checkboxes) to update the contents of the invisible fields. One can then use the 'with' attribute of [f:validateButton](https://jenkins-ci.org/maven-site/jenkins-core/jelly-taglib-ref.html#form:validateButton) to send the value of this hidden field.

Comment: NOTE: the javascript made use of the _document.getElementById_ to get the hidden field textbox, and the _document.getElementsByName_ to get the repeated components

Comment: Thanks for answering your question. I had the same one.